# Counting number of lines in file regardless of line ending char

Tags: grep, wc

Suppose I'm given a variety of files, some with line endings of `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`. How would I efficiently count the number of lines in a file when I don't know what to expect beforehand?

Obviously `wc -l` won't work if there are Mac line endings.

Grep appears to be very inaccurate when used:

```
grep -o '\r' /path/to/file.txt | wc -l
```

Gives 1041 lines but there are actually only 299 lines, and `nano` is able to confirm that by auto-converting from Mac format.

It also doesn't provide the versatility I was hoping for because `grep -o '[\r\n]+' /path/to/file.txt | wc -l` returns a count of 0.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: convert the files to end with `\n` and then use `wc`?

Comment: What do you want the number to be for a file like `1\n2\n3\r4`? Is this 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 lines? It doesn't end with a "line ending", so could be rejected as binary and have 0 lines, it could be a Mac file with 1 '\r' in it, it could be unix with 2 '\n' in it, it could be unix with 2 and a bit lines in it, or something with 3 and a bit lines in it. My point is that the concept of `lines` is a bit vague. What are you going to use the information for?

Comment: These are delimited files I'm scanning, usually tab or comma delimited. Each line is supposed to be terminated with a new line character, but that character will vary depending on the source. The files can be huge, so rewriting the entire file to use a different line ending would not be practical. I still need the line count.

Comment: Could you try `cat file.txt | tr -c -d '\r' | wc -c ` to count the number of `\r` in the file?  When I tried your `grep` command, I only found matches for the letter `"r"`.

Comment: @JigglyNaga that returned the correct number of lines, but how memory efficient is piping it thru three commands like that? I know `wc -l` is crazy fast and memory efficient on large files.

Comment: @eComEvo I didn't suggest that as a solution, but as a request for more information about your input file.  But if you experience slowdown, please include your measurements (using `time`).

Comment: @JigglyNaga using `wc -l < file.txt` requires `0m0.011s` and `cat file.txt | tr -c -d '\r\n' | wc -c` requires `0m0.044s` so 4 times slower but still pretty damn fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `grep` command was giving far too many matches because `grep` uses [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03), which don't give special meaning to `\r` -- it was counting occurrences of the letter "r".

`tr` *does* recognise `\n` and `\r`, so it can find all the matches, and let `wc -c` count them byte-by-byte:

```
tr -d -c '\n\r' < file.txt | wc -c
```

But as your file may also contain Windows/DOS line-endings (`\r\n`), those would get counted twice.  You will need an additional step to convert any DOS-style line-endings to one of the other forms, then count individual line-end characters as before:

```
sed 's/\r$//' file.txt | tr -d -c '\n\r' | wc -c
```

Unfortunately, `sed` doesn't always recognize `\r`, either.  You may need to use some other way to specify a carriage-return, such as the shell's own escaping, the `echo` command, or putting the sed script in a file.

Comment: Really only concerned with Mac, Unix and Windows files. DOS just doesn't happen for this use case so the first command works. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was using "DOS line-endings" as a shorthand for "DOS and Windows", ie. `\r\n`, sometimes described as "CR LF".  Edited for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
gawk 'END {print NR}' RS='\r|\n|\r\n' file.txt
```

The `RS` variable specifies what is considered a newline to `gawk`, in this case a regular expression.

Comment: I would change `RS='\r\n?|\n'` but that's just stylistic.